# The hardest crossword you'll do today!

Tags: no-computers, anagram, crosswords, seasonal

This could well be the most difficult crossword you do today!

***Please note that the use of Google and other search engines is STRICTLY FORBIDDEN.***

(Of course, I have no way of policing this, but if you *do* decide to cheat and comb the Internet for the answers then the letters in the shaded squares can be rearranged to describe what I think of you!)

Good luck!

[image]

> **Across:**
>   1. Object resembled by the trichiuriform fish *Trichiurus lepturus*. (4)
>   5. Given name of US director Hooper, who directed the 1995 adaptation of the Stephen King short story, *The Mangler*. (4)
>   7. German royal house producing 4 British monarchs who shared their name with the thoroughfare on which South Woodford’s tube station is situated. (7)
>   8. Family of flowering plants including spinach (*Spinacia oleracea*) and beet (*Beta vulgaris*). (13)
>   10. Alternative name of the evergreen tree, *Pouteria campechenia*, whose fruit is commonly known as an ‘egg fruit’. (8)
>   11. Battle of 14 March 1590, during the French Wars of Religion, fought on the plains of Épieds in Eure, France. (4)
>   12. Department of northern France, home to the commune of Épieds, site of the 16th century Battle of Ivry. (4)
>   13. Common name of the fruit of the canistel (*Pouteria campechenia*), an evergreen tree native to Latin America. (3,5)
>   15. London tube station formerly known as 'George Lane' after the street on which it stands. (5,8)
>   18. Stephen King short story, *The _______*, adapted for the big screen by Tobe Hooper in 1995. (7)
>   19. “____’s fingers” – a colloquial name of the okra plant (*Abelmoschus esculentus*). (4)
>   20. Ancient country, neighbour of Edom and positioned on “The King’s Highway”, the trade route linking Egypt and Mesopotamia. (4)
>
> **Down:**
>   2. Kingdom established in the 13th century BC, bordering Moab and drawing much of its livelihood from the caravan trade between north Africa and southwest Asia. (4)
>   3. Surgical procedure carried out for conditions including cancer, enlarged thyroid gland (“goitre”) and Graves’ disease. (13)
>   4. Swelling in the neck caused by enlargement of the thyroid gland, sometimes treated surgically with a thyroidectomy. (6)
>   5. Pertaining to the genus *Trichiurus* or family *Trichiuridae* (e.g. the beltfish, *Trichiurus lepturus*). (13)
>   6. Genus of the beet, member of the *Amaranthaceae* family of plants. (4)
>   9. North African country at the end of “The King’s Highway”, a historic trade route passing through Edom, Moab and other ancient kingdoms. (5)
>   10. Two-player board game, contested in the four FIDE Grand Prix 2019 tournament events held sequentially in Moscow, Riga, Hamburg and Jerusalem. (5)
>   14. ______ Lane, road in the London suburb of South Woodford; also the given name of several British monarchs in the Hanover dynasty. (6)
>   16. Plant of the *Abelmoschus* genus, alternatively known as “gumbo” or “lady’s fingers”. (4)
>   17. European city which hosted the second event of the FIDE Grand Prix series of chess tournaments in 2019. (4)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Finished crossword

> [image]

No googling is required because

> Each answer is given away by another clue:
>
>  **Across:**
>  1. Object resembled by the **trichiuriform** [5d] fish *Trichiurus lepturus*. (4)
>  5. Given name of US director Hooper, who directed the 1995 adaptation of the Stephen King short story, *The **Mangler*** [18a]. (4)
>  7. German royal house producing 4 British monarchs who shared their name with the thoroughfare on which **South Woodford**’s [15a] tube station is situated. (7)
>  8. Family of flowering plants including spinach (*Spinacia oleracea*) and beet (***Beta*** [6d] *vulgaris*). (13)
>  10. Alternative name of the evergreen tree, *Pouteria campechenia*, whose fruit is commonly known as an ‘**egg fruit**’ [13a]. (8)
>  11. Battle of 14 March 1590, during the French Wars of Religion, fought on the plains of Épieds in **Eure** [12a], France. (4)
>  12. Department of northern France, home to the commune of Épieds, site of the 16th century Battle of **Ivry** [11a]. (4)
>  13. Common name of the fruit of the **canistel** [10a] (*Pouteria campechenia*), an evergreen tree native to Latin America. (3,5)
>  15. London tube station formerly known as '**George** [14d] Lane' after the street on which it stands. (5,8)
>  18. Stephen King short story, *The _______*, adapted for the big screen by **Tobe** [5a] Hooper in 1995. (7)
>  19. “____’s fingers” – a colloquial name of the **okra** [16d] plant (*Abelmoschus esculentus*). (4)
>  20. Ancient country, neighbour of Edom and positioned on “The King’s Highway”, the trade route linking **Egypt** [9d] and Mesopotamia. (4)
>
>  **Down:**
>  2. Kingdom established in the 13th century BC, bordering **Moab** [20a] and drawing much of its livelihood from the caravan trade between north Africa and southwest Asia. (4)
>  3. Surgical procedure carried out for conditions including cancer, enlarged thyroid gland (“**goitre**”) [4d] and Graves’ disease. (13)
>  4. Swelling in the neck caused by enlargement of the thyroid gland, sometimes treated surgically with a **thyroidectomy** [3d]. (6)
>  5. Pertaining to the genus *Trichiurus* or family *Trichiuridae* (e.g. the **belt**fish [1a], *Trichiurus lepturus*). (13)
>  6. Genus of the beet, member of the ***Amaranthaceae*** [8a] family of plants. (4)
>  9. North African country at the end of “The King’s Highway”, a historic trade route passing through **Edom**, [2d] Moab and other ancient kingdoms. (5)
>  10. Two-player board game, contested in the four FIDE Grand Prix 2019 tournament events held sequentially in Moscow, **Riga**, [17d] Hamburg and Jerusalem. (5)
>  14. ______ Lane, road in the London suburb of South Woodford; also the given name of several British monarchs in the **Hanover** [7a] dynasty. (6)
>  16. Plant of the *Abelmoschus* genus, alternatively known as “gumbo” or “**lady**’s [19a] fingers”. (4)
>  17. European city which hosted the second event of the FIDE Grand Prix series of **chess** [10d] tournaments in 2019. (4)

The final message is

> APRIL FOOL, formed by anagramming letters in the shaded squares.

Comment: Well done jafe - all correct! Out of interest, which was the giveaway clue you first spotted?

Comment: @Stiv The "a-ha" clue was 18, although I did wonder about the similarity of 11 and 12 before that. This was a really funny idea, perfect fit for today :)

Comment: Ha, great - thanks jafe! It's taken me a whole week to finalise the grid design and find compatible clues - started over so many times when things weren't fitting! Glad you appreciate it :)

Comment: It might be good (if you get a chance) to add the list of clues into your second spoiler with the giveaways emphasised, just for completeness... Thanks :)

Comment: @Stiv Now done!

Comment: Perfect :) Thanks jafe - the checkmark is yours!

Comment: This is quite similar to a test given in the first book of the Mysterious Benedict Society series :)

Comment: @sunfishho I've just recently begun watching the Disney+ TV series of the Mysterious Benedict Society, and I now understand what you mean :) Really enjoying the series by the way - will have to sniff out the books some time...